# Properties of a square matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning, matrix-calculus

I have square matrix $A$ and in some part of my exercise I want to show that this matrix has not eigenvalue $\lambda =0$. Is there any property I can use without calculating characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Show that it is non-singular.

Comment: Calculate its rank or determinant, say, by row-elimination. The matrix should have then trivial kernel, so would be invertible.

Comment: Determinant equals product of eigenvalues.